# How to count each item in Oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, count

Help, this is my query

```
SELECT distinct id, trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str 
FROM (SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(to_char(advantages1), '"|\[|\]', '') str 
      FROM feedbacks) t
CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
order by str
```

and here's the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zhjP.png)

So, i want to make another column to count the result of each number in str. For example

```
STR           TOTAL
110             1
111             2
112             2
113             4
114             1
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: i have given a sample data in description

Comment: . . No, you have not.  I have no idea what `feedbacks` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
select trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str , count(distinct id) total
from (select id, regexp_replace(to_char(advantages1), '"|\[|\]', '') str from feedbacks) t
connect by instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
group by trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level))
order by str
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a column to current SELECT-list, you'd need a `COUNT() OVER()` analytic function, but values of this column are repeated for each `str` value.

As looking at the expected result set, you want to distinctly count the result of the current query. The straightforward method is nesting this query :

```
SELECT str, COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM ( <your_current_query_without_order_by_part> )
 GROUP BY str
 ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(str)
```